# is it possible to create a "cout <<" function in Python?

Tags: python

Unlike C++ `cout <<`, Python `print()` function prints the passed arguments with an endline/newline and sometimes I found it annoying having multiple lines in terminal.
I know I can use the `print(var1, end='')` or `sys.stderr.write()` from sys library but it's too long and quite hard to read.
What I think is that may be I can make a `cout<<` operator in python and prints variables or values without new line at the end

```
# Example in Python:
for x in range(3):
    print(x)

# Output:
0
1
2

# In C++:    
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
    cout << x << ' ';
}

# output:
0 1 2
```

Also, '<<' is much easier to type because the key is in the lower portion of the keyboard unlike parenthesis.

Comment: `print(x, end=' ')`

Comment: Your requirement (print without a newline character) and your idea of implementation (a cpp-like operator) seems totally unrelated of each other. Why would this specific technical detail have anything to do with the actual requirement?

Comment: You can use `print()` as like `cout' in all aspect. Like  `end=" ", end='\t" ` etc

Comment: duplicate was first google result for "python print without newline"

Answer (score 2):

Use end parameter in print function:

```
for x in range(3):
    print(x, end=' ')

# output:
0 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for

```
print(var1,end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print(x, end = " ")
```